# Leaflet + Mapbox tiles is it really free?

Tags: leaflet, mapbox

Using the leaflet [quickstart](https://leafletjs.com/examples/quick-start/#setting-up-the-map), it is suggested to use mapbox tiles, however [mapbox plan](https://www.mapbox.com/pricing/) has free up until certain map view.

There are two type of tiles url I tried:

1. `var urlTile = "https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/v4/{id}/{z}/{x}/{y}.png?access_token={accessToken}";` which correspond with map list from [here](https://www.mapbox.com/api-documentation/#maps)
2. `var urlTile = "https://api.mapbox.com/styles/v1/mapbox/{id}/tiles/{z}/{x}/{y}?access_token={accessToken}";` which uses predefined map list from [here](https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/api/#map)

I tried both url api (in localhost) and see my Mapbox account dashboard statistic usage is still empty. So is it actually free or not, anyone has used it in production?

Comment: Mapbox pricing is described here - https://www.mapbox.com/pricing/ - the free tier applies to public and free-to-access apps. For private or pay-for apps you don't get a free tier.

Comment: See also http://leaflet-extras.github.io/leaflet-providers/preview/

Comment: Note that your quota usage might not be updated in real time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a day later, I see the statistic started to have map view count, as @ghybs said it might not updated in realtime. So its free up certain map view as described in this [mapbox plan](https://www.mapbox.com/pricing/)